# get index value from string representing array jquery

Tags: javascript, string

given string is

```
var strg = "RoomItemsQuantity[items][1][itemId]"
```

I'm having the above string value.How can i get itemId from the string.

```
var index = strg.lastIndexOf("[");
var fnstrg = strg.substr(index+1);
var fnstrg = fnstrg.replace("]","");
```

I've done like this is there any easiest way to do this?

thanks,

Comment: Is `[1]` portion fixed..?

Comment: Is `itemId` part of the string or you are showing that as a placeholder for some value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code...

```
var arr = "RoomItemsQuantity[items][1][itemId]".replace(/]/g, "").split("[")
```

Will result in an array like this:

```
["RoomItemsQuantity", "items", "1", "itemId"]
```

Then...

```
arr[arr.length - 1]
```

Will give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If the above pattern is fixed, then you could use the following trick :

```
var myString = "RoomItemsQuantity[items][1][itemId]";
var myItemId = (myString+"[").split("][")[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression like:

```
('RoomItemsQuantity[items][1][itemId]'.match(/([^\[]+)\]$/) || [])[1] // itemId
```

You can also use lookahead or lookbehind but support may not be available.